# select field from dictionary table using join in Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have 2 database tables. One with Master Recors and one with detail records using a dictionary structure.

I wanna query some fields from the detailstable which is returning multiple rows with all the same header ID.

is there a way to create a custom record using linq joining both tables

example

master table:
ID
MasterName 
Date 
...

details table
ID
MasterID
Key
Value

psuedo code:
     from master in context.mastertable
     Join detail in context.detailstable
     on master.ID == detail.masterID
     SELECT new CustomClass{
         ID = master.ID,
         Name = master.MasterName
         Customfield = (detailsvalue.where key == "customfield") + (detailvalue.where key == "customfield2")
         };

hope someone can help me.

grtz Luuk Krijnen

Answer (score 1):

You could use anonymous types created within Join() method.

```
  List<Master> list1 = new List<Master>(){
    new Master(){ Id=1, Name="Name1"},
    new Master(){ Id=2, Name="Name2"}};

  List<Detail> list2 = new List<Detail>(){
    new Detail(){ Id=1, MasterId=1, Description="Description1"},
    new Detail(){ Id=2, MasterId=1, Description="Description2"},
    new Detail(){ Id=3, MasterId=1, Description="Description3"},
    new Detail(){ Id=4, MasterId=2, Description="Description4"},
    new Detail(){ Id=5, MasterId=2, Description="Description5"}};

  // IEnumerable of anonymous types
  var result = list1.Join(list2, m => m.Id, d => d.MasterId, (m, d) => new { Id = m.Id, Name = m.Name, Description = d.Description });

  foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id + " " + item.Name + " " + item.Description + Environment.NewLine);

  // Returns
  // 1 Name1 Description1
  // 1 Name1 Description2
  // 1 Name1 Description3
  // 2 Name2 Description4
  // 2 Name2 Description5
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work?:

```
var query = from master in context.masterTable
            join detail in context.detailTable
            on master.Id == detail.masterId
            where detail.Key == "customField" || detail.Key == "customField2"
            select new
            {
                id = master.Id,
                name = master.Name,
                customField = detail.Key
            };
```

If not, elaborate a bit more on what exactly you're looking for. I.E. Describe how your data is stored and the end result you're hoping to get out of this query.